# Liferay wrong autoincrement

Tags: liferay, auto-increment

I have Liferay 6.2.

I have a portlet that use MySql database.

I have a table **persons**:

```
Id | Name | Info
```

**Id** is auto-increment, so in service.xml i have:

```
<column name="Id" type="long" primary="true" id-type="increment" />
```

I have a development machine.
I have 100 rows already available in the mysql table **persons**.
I entered information within the table **persons** via a sql query and I used the **id** starting from 300 up to 600.
I used a Liferay backend tool to update the database cache. When I enter a new row with the application (portlet), the id is 601. It's correct.

I have a production machine, I performed the same operation except for emptying the database cache because for some reason I can not do it.

When I insert a new row the with the portlet **id** is 101 and not 601.

When will I come to ** id ** 199 what will happen when I insert a new line?

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you see the ids on "hundreds", you might just see the default increment value for Liferay entities:

From [portal.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Counter):

```
# Set the number of increments between database updates to the Counter table. 
# this value to a higher number for better performance.
# Defaults:

 counter.increment=100
```

You can test for this behavior by either creating 101 objects (where object #101 wou then get 700 as an id) or by shutting down the server that you used to create the #101 object and restart, then create a new object: The granularity of 100 would mean that the next 100 ids will be allocated and #700 will be picked next.

> When will I come to ** id ** 199 what will happen when I insert a new line?

It's easy to find out...

> What can I do to solve the problem?

Validate *that* there is a problem. There might be no need to solve anything

> I have a development machine. I have 100 rows already available in the mysql table persons. I entered information within the table persons via a sql query and I used the id starting from 300 up to 600

It's a quite bad idea to do so when you otherwise rely on automatic id construction. Liferay's Service Builder can't rely on id generation in the database, as every database behaves slightly different in that regard.

Liferay's id generation - when it follows the mechanism that I've described above - is done through [CounterLocalService](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/counter/service/CounterLocalServiceUtil.html). You can make calls to this service to advance the Ids for your entity (use your entity's class name as key) in case you do something manually to your database.

You should *never* change any Liferay entity on the database directly. If you have your own servicebuilder-generated entities, you might have a point, but my recommendation would be to choose one method of writing/accessing the data and stick with it.

Comment: I validate that there is the problem. Liferay can't insert a new row if ID is already present. The id grow anway but if the id exists Liferay throw an error. I asked to the man of production machine to restart the server and the problem is disapperead. Thank you.